# window.requestFileSystem contemporary trigger 'success' and 'error' callback?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm omitting some code, but this is the core:

```
function App() {

var self = this;

window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 
                          0, self.onGotFs, self.onError(1) );


... omitted ....


this.onGotFs = function(file_system) {
    console.log("gotFs:" + file_system.root.full_path );
    self.file_system = file_system;
};

this.onError = function(id) {
    console.log("app error #" + id);
};


    ... omittted ...

}
```

Looking at the console I see both messages

```
app error #1
gotFs !
```

Please Note: i can't see the file_system.root.full_path string. It's not printend

So the main question is:

### Why requestFileSystem triggers both success and error callback ?

Probably I'm missing some knowledge base; i'm an html5 newbie

### Documentation

I see this definition on [w3c documentation - paragraph 4.4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/file-system-api/)

```
interface LocalFileSystem {
    const unsigned short TEMPORARY = 0;
    const unsigned short PERSISTENT = 1;
    void requestFileSystem (unsigned short type, unsigned long long size, FileSystemCallback successCallback, optional ErrorCallback errorCallback);
    void resolveLocalFileSystemURL (DOMString url, EntryCallback successCallback, optional ErrorCallback errorCallback);
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
self.onError(1)
```

This calls `onError` **immediately** and passes the result to `requestFileSystem`.

You need to pass a function that calls `onError`:

```
requestFileSystem(..., function() { self.onError(1); });
```

Also, `onGotFs` is called with the wrong `this`.  You can either pass a similar function or pass `self.onGotFs.bind(self)`

Comment: What do you mean by' Also, onGotFs is called with the wrong this' ? Please update your answer, it's interesting !

Comment: `this.onGotFs` does not refer to `this` in its body so it's superfluous to bind

Comment: The code is all inside an var function app() { }, so it's why i'm using this. One moment and I'll update the code into my question

Comment: I tried 
window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function() { self.onGotFs; }, function() { self.onError(1); } ) but it's not working, none of them is triggered, and no error shown ..